# Whether recursive relationship is a different version of principle of mathematical induction?

Tags: recurrence-relations

In connection with the question

> [I can't get satisfied with such 'so on' type logic. Is there a better way to solve it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458432/i-cant-get-satisfied-with-such-so-on-type-logic-is-there-a-better-way-to-sol)

and the responses recieved I would like to know whether recursive relationship is a different version of principle of mathematical induction?

I can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458432/i-cant-get-satisfied-with-such-so-on-type-logic-is-there-a-better-way-to-sol) $x_1\in X$ and $x_n\in X\implies~\exists~x_{n+1}\in X$ such that $d(x,x_n)>d(x,x_{n+1}).$ Can we conclude by induction that $\exists~\{x_n\}\subset X$ such that $d(x,x_1)>d(x,x_2)>...?$